# Fibonacci numbers python, what should i learn to be a better programmer (self taught )

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
fiblist = []
while True:     
     newNum = n1 + n2
     fiblist.append(newNum)
     n1 = n2
     n2 = newNum
     if newNum >= 10000:
          print(flist)
          break
```

beginner programmer: is there an easier way to write this or some other more effective way

Comment: In python, variables and functions are name `lowercase_with_underscores` not `camelCase`

Comment: [Many code examples for Fibonacci](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Python) in Python and other programming languages.

Comment: May I recommend https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for open-ended questions about the quality of your code, like this one? Stack Overflow is more suitable for specific questions.

Answer (score 5):

Your code can be simplified to the following.

```
fiblist = [0, 1]                # initialize with first two numbers
while fiblist[-1] < 10000:      # while last number <= threshold
  fiblist.append(fiblist[-1] + fiblist[-2])  # next is sum of last 2 numbers

print(fiblist)
```

**Explanation** (provided since you asked for things to learn to be a better coder)

Simplification of your code to above based upon principles from two references

1. Style guide: [Python Style
   Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#overriding-principle)
2. Python Mantra: [Zen of
       Python](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2018/08/17/the-zen-of-python-explained/)

*Using reference 1*

PEP 8 Guide: "Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability".  This is Python-specific.  Other languages (i.e. C++, Java, Clojure, JavaScript, etc.) have their own preferred styles.  So for Python: new_num rather than newNum (i.e. not camelCase for variables and function names).

*Using reference 2*

Zen of Python: "Simple is better than complex".

Your while loop is overly complicated by focusing on two objectives, namely: (1) generating fibonacci numbers, and (2) printing fibonacci numbers). From [Single Repository Principle](https://medium.com/unbabel/refactoring-a-python-codebase-using-the-single-responsibility-principle-ed1367baefd6) we know less is better than more (i.e. objectives).

Simplify by creating code blocks with single rather than multiple objectives.

```
while True:                # objective 1--generating fib numbers
     newNum = n1 + n2
     fiblist.append(newNum)
     n1 = n2
     n2 = newNum
     if newNum >= 10000:
          break

print(fiblist)             # objective 2--printing fib numbers
```

Next, we simplify by improving [robustness](https://medium.com/unbabel/refactoring-a-python-codebase-using-the-single-responsibility-principle-ed1367baefd6).  *Robustness* — "Simple objects allow you to focus on the specificities of each task individually and reduces the amount of input/output variables you need to consider at any given time".  fiblist is a simple object we can use to replace n1, n2, and new_num as follows:

```
fiblist[-2] is n1
fiblist[-1] is n2
fiblist[-1] is new_num (after append)
```

Using *robustness* the code becomes:

```
while fiblist[-1] < 10000:
    fiblist.append(fiblist[-1] + fiblist[-2])
```

In order for this to work, we need to initialize fiblist before the while loop to:

```
fiblist = [0, 1]
```

Thus with this sequence of simplifications, we obtain the suggested code.

**Additional References to be a better Programmer**

3. [Fibonacci Code
   Examples](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Python)
4. [What Python tutorials should I
   read](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Answer (score 0):

1. use generators or iterators in python to generate a series than creating a list.
2. python simplifies swapping variables as `a, b = b , a`

```py
def fibanocci(n1, n2, size):
    for i in range(size):
        yield n1
        n1, n2 = n2, n1 + n2
```

Now to use the series,

```
>>> for i in fibanocci(1, 1, 5):
...     print(i)
... 
1
1
2
3
5
>>>
```